# Why am I getting a weight matrix full of NaNs?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, neural-network, pca

(Hebbian learning)

I was given the task of programming the Oja's learning rule and Sanger's learning rule in Matlab, to train a neural network. This NN has 6 inputs and 4 outputs, and my training set comes from a multivariate uniform distribution, such as Xi ~ U(-ai,ai) and ai≠aj, for all i≠j

These are the most relevant files (Most comments and oja.m were not included)

main.m

```
TS = generarVectoresUnif(6, [1, 4, 9, 36, 25, 16], 512);
TS = TS';
W = unifrnd(0,1,[4,6]);
% it not very fast. That's why I put 500 iterations
W_sanger = sanger(W,TS,500, 0.05)
```

generarVectoresUnif.m

```
function [ TS ] = generarVectoresUnif( dim, rangos, n )
dimensiones = int8(dim);
tamanio = int32(n);
TS = [];

for i = 1:dimensiones
   TS = [TS, unifrnd(-rangos(i), rangos(i), [tamanio, 1]) ];
end
```

sanger.m

( NOTE:
**W** is a 4 x 6 size matrix.
**Wi** is the weight vector for the *i*-th output.
**Wij** = **(Wi)j**.
In the example, **TS** is a 6 x 512 size matrix
)

```
function [ W ] = sanger( W_init, trainingset, iteraciones , eta)

W = W_init;

% obtiene los tamaños desde los parametros de entrada
size_input = size(W,2);
size_output = size(W,1);
n_patterns = size(trainingset, 2);


% one-tenth part
diezmo = iteraciones/10;


for it = 1:iteraciones

   if 0 == mod(it, diezmo)
      disp(horzcat('Iteracion numero ', num2str(it), ' de ',num2str(iteraciones)));
   end

   % for each pattern
   for u = 1:n_patrones

      DeltaW = zeros(size(W));

      % Vi = sum{j=1...N} Wij * Xj
      V = W * trainingset(:,u);

      % sumatorias(i,j) is going to replace sum{k=1..i} Vk*Wkj
      sumatorias = zeros(size_output,size_input);
      for j = 1:size_input
         for k = 1:size_output
             % sumar de 1 hasta i, sin hacer otro ciclo
             sumatorias(k,j) = (V' .* [ones(1,k), zeros(1,size_output-k)]) * W(:,j);
         end
      end

       % calcula la variacion
       for i = 1:size_output
          for j=1:size_input
             % Delta Wij = eta * Vi * ( xj - sum{k=1..i} Vk*Wkj )
              DeltaW(i,j) = eta * V(i,1) * (trainingset(j,u) - sumatorias(i,j));
          end
       end

       W = W + DeltaW;      
       %W = 1/norm(W) * W; %<---is it necessary? [Hertz] doesn't mention it

  end

end
```

Could you tell me please what I am doing wrong? Values of the matrix grow really fast.
I have the same problem with oja.m

I've tried:

- Replacing *eta* by *1/it* --->NaN
- Replacing *eta* by an exponential function of number of iterations --->ok, but it's not what I expected
- Uncommenting **W = 1/norm(W) * W;**. This actually works, but it shouldn't be necessary, or should it?

Comment: ([Hebbian Learning](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hebbian+learning))

Comment: [Oja's and Sanger's learning rules](http://books.google.com/books?id=RTtvUVU_xL4C&pg=PA209&dq=oja+sanger+rule&hl=en&ei=6z-kTqDSL4WItweFrbzjBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=oja%20sanger%20rule&f=false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need small values of eta. Consider your update rule:

```
DeltaW(i,j) = eta * V(i,1) * (trainingset(j,u) - sumatorias(i,j));
```

If eta is large, `DeltaW` is likely to have a large absolute value (i.e. very big, e.g. 100000, or very small, e.g. -111111). The next time around the loop `sumatorias(i,j)` will be quite large, because it is a function of the weights. The more iterations you have, the larger your weights will become, eventually leading to an overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. After **several** tries, I made it work.

I choose a relatively small value of *eta*: 0.00001

```
W_sanger = sanger(W,TS,1000, 0.00001)
```

It's still slow, because of not taking advantage of matrix multiplication, which is optimized by Matlab.

I hope it helps someone else to not repeat the same mistake.

Regards!